# How to show the integration plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a written a program which creates following plot. To draw the following plot I have data in two arrays.

[image]

In the same plot I want to show the integration plot which looks like following image. Integration plot shows using red line. Can anyone help me to do that. I am using matplotlib to print the first plot.

[image]

Comment: Do you need help calculating the integrated array, or are you simply looking to plot two curves on top of one another? Also, are you using any of `numpy` or `scipy`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` function. This will do exactly what you want. If you have two arrays `x` and `y`, you can pass them so that the integrated signal `y_int` is given by:

```
y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(y, x, initial=0)
```

This is taken directly from the `scipy` documentation at [this link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html).

Plotting should then be as easy as calling `plt.plot(x, y, x, y_int)`.

Also, this code assumes that you have done the following imports:

```
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thank you so much @GJStein. By the way I have written a function to do the integration.

Comment: Could you either post it as an answer or upvote/accept mine?